# AJAX- getting a specific array value in post

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

Im making a like system and am encorporating ajax to make it smooth. Everything works okay except it always defaults to the last post in for loop. My thinking is there is no way for the javascript to know which element of id "like" to post to.

main.js:

```
   $(".like>a").click(function() {

    $.post(base_url + "index.php/userprofile/like_post/", { post : post }, function(data) {

        alert('liked');

    }, "json");

    return false;

});
```

Im passing through the post variable from the view file. I grab the postID of each post.

userprofile_view.php:

```
            <?php foreach ($posts as $post) 
            { ?>
            <?php $postID = $this->model_posts->getPostData('id', $post->post); ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var post = "<?php echo $postID; ?>";
                var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
            </script>
```

model_posts.php:

```
function likePost($post) {
    $data['user_ID'] = $this->session->userdata('id');
    $data['post_liked'] = $post;

    $insert = $this->db->insert('user_post_likes', $data);
    return $insert;
}
```

userprofile.php(controller):

```
    public function like_post() {
    $this->load->model('model_posts');

    $post = $this->input->post('post');

    $this->model_posts->likePost($post);
}
```

If someone couldhelp me out that would be great!

Comment: what is the `post` in the click handler... you need to share more context to that

Comment: the variable that im specifiying in the view

Comment: whether `$(".like>a").click(function() {` is done in a loop?

Comment: where is the `.like > a` element gets created.... the problem is you are creating a global variable `post` in a loop.. so its value is getting overriden every time.. thus it will have only the last value

Comment: Ive came to that conclusion, I just dont know how to fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63262/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-divergent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your usage of a global variable in a loop, so the variable will have only the last value of the loop.

You can use a `data-*` attribute like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>"; 
</script>   

<?php foreach ($posts as $post) 
{ ?> 
<?php $postID = $this->model_posts->getPostData('id', $post->post); ?> 

<div class='posts'> 

<div class='posts_img'> 
<img src="<?php echo base_url() . 'img/profilepictures/thumbs/' . $profilepicture?>"> 
</div> 

<div class='posts_user'>    
<strong><?php echo $prefname; ?></strong>   
</div>  

<div class='posts_date'> 
<?php echo $this->model_posts->getPostTime($post->post); ?> 
</div> 

<div class='post'> 
<p><?php echo $post->post ?></p> 
</div> 

<?php if($this->model_posts->doesUserLike($me, $postID)) { ?> 
<div class='unlike'> 
<?php echo anchor('userprofile/unlike_post/' . $me . '/' . $postID, 'unlike'); ?> 
</div> 
<?php } else { ?> 
<div class='like' data-post="<?php echo $postID; ?>"> 
<?php echo anchor('#', 'like', array('id' => 'like')); ?> 
</div> 
<?php } ?>
```

then

```
$(".like>a").click(function () {

    var post = $(this).parent().attr('data-post'); 
    $.post(base_url + "index.php/userprofile/like_post/", {
        post: post
    }, function (data) {

        alert('liked');

    }, "json");

    return false;

});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var post = "<?php echo $postID; ?>";
    var base_url = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>";
</script>
```

This is your problem. You're declaring these variables in global scope. So every time your PHP foreach loop iterates, you're redefining the variable in global scope, overwriting the previous value.

Instead, set an `id` attribute on each `<a>` tag to be the `$postID`, and get that ID in your click handler, like so:

```
$(".like>a").click(function() {
    var post = this.id;
    $.post(base_url + "index.php/userprofile/like_post/", { post : post }, function(data) {
        alert('liked');
    }, "json");

    return false;
});
```

You would have to modify the code that creates the `<a>` tags to include the `id` attribute with the `$postID` value assigned to it...I don't see that part included in your code samples.

Comment: Yea how can I fix that

Answer (score 0):

if you're sending same ID field with different values stop, send unique IDs with selected values OR send ID with values as post array, PHP can deal with it